# Unreal Engine 4 Line Trace Error

Tags: c++, raycasting, unreal-4

This is the error that I am currently facing:

```
PlayerPawn.cpp.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: bool __cdecl APlayerPawn::Trace(struct FHitResult,class AActor *,struct FVector const &,struct FVector const &)" (?Trace@APlayerPawn@@QEAA_NUFHitResult@@PEAVAActor@@AEBUFVector@@2@Z) referenced in function "public: void __cdecl APlayerPawn::SelectActor(void)" (?SelectActor@APlayerPawn@@QEAAXXZ)
1>C:\Users\ *****\Documents\Unreal Projects\TurnBasedStrategy\Binaries\Win64\UE4Editor-TurnBasedStrategy.dll : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

I know it has something to do with the LineTrace that I am performing, but I'm not sure what exactly is causing the error. It says there is an external that is unresolved, but I can't seem to figure out what that external is.

This is the header file PlayerPawn.h

```
// Fill out your copyright notice in the Description page of Project Settings.

#pragma once

#include "GameFramework/Pawn.h"
#include "PlayerPawn.generated.h"


UCLASS()
class TURNBASEDSTRATEGY_API APlayerPawn : public APawn
{
    GENERATED_BODY()

public:
    // Sets default values for this pawn's properties
    APlayerPawn();

    // Called when the game starts or when spawned
    virtual void BeginPlay() override;

    // Called every frame
    virtual void Tick( float DeltaSeconds ) override;

    // Called to bind functionality to input
    virtual void SetupPlayerInputComponent(class UInputComponent* InputComponent) override;



protected:
    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere)
    USpringArmComponent* CameraSpringArm;
    UCameraComponent* Camera;

    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere)
    float CameraMoveSpeed;
    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere)
    float CameraZoomSpeed;
    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere)
    float CameraRotateSpeed;

    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere)
    FVector2D MaxLimits;
    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere)
    FVector2D MinLimits;
    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere)
    FVector2D HeightLimits;

    //Input variables
    FVector2D MovementInput;
    float ZoomInput;

    bool bZoomingIn;
    bool bZoomingOut;

    //Input functions
    void MoveForward(float AxisValue);
    void MoveSide(float AxisValue);
    void ZoomCamera(float AxisValue);
    void Select();
    void Attack();
    void ZoomIn();
    void ZoomOut();


    FHitResult HitActor;
    AActor* SelectedActor;

    bool Trace(FHitResult HitActor, AActor* ActorToIgnore, const FVector& Start, const FVector& End);

    void SelectActor();

};
```

And this is the source file PlayerPawn.cpp

```
// Fill out your copyright notice in the Description page of Project Settings.

#include "TurnBasedStrategy.h"
#include "PlayerPawn.h"


// Sets default values
APlayerPawn::APlayerPawn()
{
    // Set this pawn to call Tick() every frame.  You can turn this off to improve performance if you don't need it.
    PrimaryActorTick.bCanEverTick = true;

    //Create components
    RootComponent = CreateDefaultSubobject<USceneComponent>(TEXT("RootComponent"));

    CameraSpringArm = CreateDefaultSubobject<USpringArmComponent>(TEXT("CameraSpringArm"));
    CameraSpringArm->AttachTo(RootComponent);
    CameraSpringArm->SetRelativeLocationAndRotation(FVector(0.0f, 0.0f, 50.0f), FRotator(-60.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
    CameraSpringArm->TargetArmLength = 200.0f;
    CameraSpringArm->bEnableCameraLag = true;
    CameraSpringArm->CameraLagSpeed = 3.0f;

    Camera = CreateDefaultSubobject<UCameraComponent>(TEXT("PlayerCamera"));
    Camera->AttachTo(CameraSpringArm, USpringArmComponent::SocketName);

    AutoPossessPlayer = EAutoReceiveInput::Player0;

    CameraMoveSpeed = 100.0f;
    CameraRotateSpeed = 10.0f;
    CameraZoomSpeed = 50.0f;

    MaxLimits = FVector2D(1000.0f, 800.0f);
    MinLimits = FVector2D(-1000.0f, -800.0f);
    HeightLimits = FVector2D(1000.0f, 0.0f);

}

// Called when the game starts or when spawned
void APlayerPawn::BeginPlay()
{
    Super::BeginPlay();

}

// Called every frame
void APlayerPawn::Tick( float DeltaTime )
{
    Super::Tick( DeltaTime );

    //Rotate actor's yaw, which will turn camera because attached to it
    //{
    //  FRotator NewRotation = GetActorRotation();
    //  NewRotation.Yaw += CameraInput.X;
    //  SetActorRotation(NewRotation);
    //}

    //Rotate  camera's pitch, but limit it so always looking downward
    //{
    //  FRotator NewRotation = CameraSpringArm->GetComponentRotation();
    //  NewRotation.Pitch = FMath::Clamp(NewRotation.Pitch + CameraInput.Y, -80.0f, -15.0f);
    //  CameraSpringArm->SetWorldRotation(NewRotation);
    //}

    //Handle movement

        if (!MovementInput.IsZero())
        {
            //Scale movement input axis values by x units per second
            MovementInput = MovementInput.GetSafeNormal() * CameraMoveSpeed;
            FVector NewLocation = GetActorLocation();
            NewLocation += GetActorForwardVector() * MovementInput.Y * DeltaTime;
            NewLocation += GetActorRightVector() * MovementInput.X * DeltaTime;
            NewLocation.Y = FMath::Clamp<float>(NewLocation.Y, MinLimits.Y, MaxLimits.Y);
            NewLocation.X = FMath::Clamp<float>(NewLocation.X, MinLimits.X, MaxLimits.X);
            SetActorLocation(NewLocation);
        }

        if (ZoomInput != 0.0f)
        {
            ZoomInput = ZoomInput * CameraZoomSpeed;
            FVector NewLocation = GetActorLocation();
            NewLocation += GetActorUpVector() * ZoomInput;
            NewLocation.Z = FMath::Clamp<float>(NewLocation.Z, HeightLimits.X, HeightLimits.Y);
            SetActorLocation(NewLocation);
            ZoomInput = 0;
        }


}

// Called to bind functionality to input
void APlayerPawn::SetupPlayerInputComponent(class UInputComponent* InputComponent)
{
    Super::SetupPlayerInputComponent(InputComponent);

    // Hook up events for zoomin
    InputComponent->BindAction("CameraZoomIn", IE_Pressed, this, &APlayerPawn::ZoomIn);
    InputComponent->BindAction("CameraZoomOut", IE_Pressed, this, &APlayerPawn::ZoomOut);
    InputComponent->BindAction("Select", IE_Pressed, this, &APlayerPawn::SelectActor);

    // Hook up every-frame handling for axis
    InputComponent->BindAxis("MoveForward", this, &APlayerPawn::MoveForward);
    InputComponent->BindAxis("MoveSide", this, &APlayerPawn::MoveSide);
}

//Input functions
void APlayerPawn::MoveForward(float AxisValue)
{
    MovementInput.Y = FMath::Clamp<float>(AxisValue, -1.0f, 1.0f);
}

void APlayerPawn::MoveSide(float AxisValue)
{
    MovementInput.X = FMath::Clamp<float>(AxisValue, -1.0f, 1.0f);
}

void APlayerPawn::ZoomIn()
{
    ZoomInput = -1.0f;

}

void APlayerPawn::ZoomOut()
{
    ZoomInput = 1.0f;
}

void APlayerPawn::SelectActor()
{
    TObjectIterator< APlayerController > PlayerController;
    FVector MouseLocation, MouseDirection;
    PlayerController->DeprojectMousePositionToWorld(MouseLocation, MouseDirection);
    //Trace(HitActor, this, Camera->GetComponentLocation(), MouseLocation);
//
    if (Trace(HitActor, this, Camera->GetComponentLocation(), MouseLocation))
    {
        SelectedActor = HitActor.GetActor();
        //SelectedActor
    }
}

bool Trace(FHitResult HitOut, AActor* ActorToIgnore, const FVector& Start, const FVector& End)
{
    FCollisionQueryParams TraceParams(FName(TEXT("Hit Trace")), true, ActorToIgnore);
    TraceParams.bTraceComplex = true;
    TraceParams.bTraceAsyncScene = true;
    TraceParams.bReturnPhysicalMaterial = false;

    //Ignore Actors
    TraceParams.AddIgnoredActor(ActorToIgnore);

    //Re-initialize hit info
    HitOut = FHitResult(ForceInit);

    //Get World Context
    TObjectIterator< APlayerController > PlayerController;
    if (!PlayerController) return false;

    //Trace
    return PlayerController->GetWorld()->LineTraceSingleByChannel(HitOut, Start, End, ECC_Pawn, TraceParams);
}
```

Comment: You forgot to class scope the definition of your `Trace` method. In your cpp, change the line `bool Trace(FHitResult HitOut, AActor* ActorToIgnore, const FVector& Start, const FVector& End)` for `bool APlayerPawn::Trace(FHitResult HitOut, AActor* ActorToIgnore, const FVector& Start, const FVector& End)`.

Comment: Omg, thank you. I would never have noticed that. Such a simple thing too. :)

Comment: Welcome the the c++ world :) Link errors are the hardest to debug. Glad I could be of help!